# Access polymer-elements variables with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

I am trying to change page with jQuery but I do not know how to access the "selected" variable.

Here is what I am trying do achieve with jQuery:

```
var tabs = document.querySelector('paper-tabs');
var pages = document.querySelector('core-animated-pages');

tabs.addEventListener('core-select', function(){
    pages.selected = tabs.selected;
});
```

And I have tried something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('paper-tabs').on('core-select', function(){
            $('core-animated-pages').attr('selected',$(this).attr('selected'));
    });
});
```

So how do I get `pages.selected` and `tabs.selected` with jQuery?

**EDIT:**
This worked for me, but I don't believe it is the optimal answer

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('paper-tabs').on('core-select', function(){
        $('core-animated-pages').find('section').removeClass('core-selected');
        $('core-animated-pages').find('section:eq('+($(this).find('.core-selected').index())+')').addClass('core-selected');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a hybrid will do..

```
$(document).on('core-select','paper-tabs', function(){
    document.querySelector('core-animated-pages').selected = this.selected;
});
```